# Give posts a particular template based on the assigned category

Tags: posts, categories, theme-development, templates

I have the following setup:

- 3 posts: `post1`, `post2`, & `post3`
- 2 categories: `cat1` & `cat2`
- 2 templates: `singe1.php` & `single2.php`

- `post1` and `post2` are assigned to `cat1`
- `post3` is assigned to `cat2`

`post1` and `post2` should use `template1` and `post3` should use `template2`

I have found this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/single-post-template/installation/
but it is for every page separate.

Is there any way to relate the post template and the category?

Comment: Are those post1, post2 and post3 are posts ? or post types ?

Comment: [This question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43067/4771) contains code to enable `single-category-name.php` templates using the `single_template` filter.

Answer (score 1):

nikolaou,

When I understand you question correct then you want to use different templates based on the categories you're using within your posts, correct?

If that's the case, then you only need one template (single.php) and a combination of `get_the_terms()` and `get_template_part()`.

```
<?php

$categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'slug');

if ( in_array('cat1', $categories) ) {
    get_template_part('partials/single', '1');
} elseif ( in_array('cat2', $categories) ) {
    get_template_part('partials/single', '2');
}

?>
```

You should place the code above within *The Loop*. The two template files are called *single-1.php* and *single-2.php* and stored within a folder called *partials*.

**Sources:**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to your advantage. In your theme, you can create template files for the different categories, if you'd like.

Let's say you have categories named `cats` and `dogs`. If you create a pair of files named `category-cats.php` and `category-dogs.php`, those files will be used as the templates for their respective categories.

You can also use the categories' IDs in the template file names. So if `cats` is category #3 and `dogs` is category #4, then `category-3.php` and `category-4.php` will be used for the respective posts.

### References

- [Template Hierarchy » Categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category)
- [Graphical Template Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm guessing that you want to assign the template without changing it (or its name). There's a filter for that called [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template). It is used to intercept WP's standard system of finding a template for a post. You would include it in your `functions.php` like this (untested):

```
function wpse254523_single_template ($single_template) {
     global $post;
     $cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
     if ($cat == 'cat1' || $cat == 'cat2')
       $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single1.php';
     elseif ($cat == 'cat3')
       $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single2.php';
     return $single_template;
     }

add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse254523_single_template' );
```